# Google Cloud Compute Engine | VPS Disappeared after some problems with the credit card billing the project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

The VPS has disappeared from my Google Cloud compute engine panel, we had sensitive project data on it.

So, my question is if it is possible to recover a VPS a this state?

I would appreciate any help or guidance.

I navigated almost the entire platform searching for any option to recover the VPS and also used several g-cloud-console commands to try to get any information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tried to touch many help channels, found this state is not reversible, the support said there is no manuall option to recover a vps after the 30 days of the server shutdown. (GCP terms).